# Characterizing compact Hausdorff spaces whose all subsets are Borel

Tags: gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I am interested in characterizing compact topological spaces all of whose  subsets are Borel. In this respect I have the following

**Conjecture.** For a compact Hausdorff space $X$ the following conditions are equivalent:

1) Each subsets of $X$ is Borel.

2) $X$ is scattered of countable scattered height.

**Remark.** The implication $(2)\Rightarrow(1)$ is true and can be proved by induction on the scattered height of $X$. So, it remains to prove $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$.

Comment: Taras, there is a related paper by wh & A.Mishchenko, published in Bull.Acad.Polon.Sci. in 1966 (or 1967?). It's in Russian (but I don't think you'd have any problem with this).

Comment: @WlodAA Thank you for the comment. I looked at the review of this paper in Zbl (https://zbmath.org/scans/241/357.gif) and found no confiramtions of this conjecture. There is however a theorem that a compact Hausdorff space is perfectly normal if all its open sets are Souslin. What is the relation of Souslinness of open set to Borelness of all subsets?

Comment: Taras, I should have said ***vaguely** related*. I'll think about your questions (I am rusty though). To me, the general topic started with the eternal claim of many of my students: *if a set is not open then it's closed (and vice versa))*. Thus at first, I introduced *student spaces*. Later I saw an exercise for Hausdorff spaces in Kelly's classic, these spaces were called the *door spaces* (I guess because a door is either open or closed).